# Display thresholds on n3-chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, n3-charts

I'm using n3-chart/line-chart (https://github.com/n3-charts/line-chart) in my angular project.
I'm wondering if there is any way of displaying thresholds in the chart? Ideally this could be done by enabling the `grid` option, and set a color for the grid on certain y-axis values. However, I haven't found any information if that is possible or not.

The only work around I could think of is to create a "threshold series" that only has two measurements, one for the min x value and one for the max x value. The chart in this codepen example demonstrates this: [http://codepen.io/ulrikl/pen/rOXNdd](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYgjMm)

So, my question is: Is this the only way of achieving thresholds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n3-charts creator here, symbols are now supported so take a look at http://n3-charts.github.io/line-chart/#/docs, jump to the Symbols section and you'll be all set, hopefully !